# how to Add List in TabBarView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, center, appbar

i want to add listviw with column .
.
.
.
.
.
..
.
.
.

.
.
.
.
.
..

in 'a' screen i want to show list.

but i can't and i've get error.
idk why.

can anyone help me please ?

this is part of my code:

```
 Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
              child: Container(
                width: 500,
                child: DefaultTabController(
                  length: 3,
                  child: Scaffold(
                    appBar: PreferredSize(
                      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
                      child: const TabBar(
                        tabs: <Widget>[
                          Tab(
                              text: "a",
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: "b",
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: "c",
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    body: const TabBarView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Center(
                            child: Text("a "),
//here i want to add listView
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text("b"),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text("c"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: can you add full widget including state class

Comment: can you send a link of chat ? i've send it to you

Comment: You can add  full widget on the question that will reproduce the error you facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just delete 'const' in TabBarView

```
            body: TabBarView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                    child: Text("a "),

                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("b"),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("c"),
                ),
              ],
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.